# How do I practically compute the Hessian of a linear-chain Conditional Random Field?

Tags: predictive-models

A linear-chain Conditional Random Field defines a pmf:

$$
\begin{align}
p(y|x) &= Z(x)^{-1} \prod_{t=1}^T \exp(\phi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x)^\intercal\theta) \\
&= \exp\left(\sum_{t=1}^T\phi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x)^\intercal\theta - \log Z(x)\right)
\end{align}
$$

The respective neg-log-likelihood becomes

$$
\begin{align}
L(\theta) &= -\log p(y\mid x) \\
&= \log Z(x) - \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x)^\intercal\theta
\end{align}
$$

I derive $\log Z(x)$ because it becomes useful:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log Z(x) &= \sum_\tilde{y} p(\tilde{y}|x) \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x) \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1}} p(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1}\mid x) \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x)
\end{align}
$$

I derive $L$ to obtain the Jacobian:
$$
\begin{align}
J_i &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i} L(\theta)\\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log Z(x) - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\sum_{t=1}^T \phi_t(y_t, y_{t-1}, x)^\intercal\theta \\
&= \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1}} p(\tilde{y}_t,\tilde{y}_{t-1}|x) \phi_{t, i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1}, x) - \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(y_t, y_{t-1}, x)
\end{align}
$$

I derive $J$ to obtain the Hessian:
$$
\begin{align}
H_{i,j} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log Z(x) \\
&= \sum_\tilde{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}p(\tilde{y}|x) \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x) \\
&= \sum_\tilde{y} p(\tilde{y}|x) \left(\sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,j}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x) - \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\log Z(x) \right) \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x) \\
&= \sum_\tilde{y} p(\tilde{y}|x) \left(\sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,j}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x)\right)\left( \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x)\right) \\
&\phantom{=}- \sum_\tilde{y} p(\tilde{y}|x) \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\log Z(x) \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x) \\
&= \sum_\tilde{y} p(\tilde{y}|x) \left(\sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,j}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x)\right)\left( \sum_{t=1}^T \phi_{t,i}(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1},x)\right) \\
&\phantom{=}- \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\log Z(x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}\log Z(x)
\end{align}
$$

For the Jacobian, I was able to determine an expression which I can practically compute in linear time using the forward-backward algorithm to compute the posterior marginals $p(\tilde{y}_t, \tilde{y}_{t-1}| x)$. For the Hessian I am stuck; I can't possibly go through all possible label sequences of length $T$, and I can't use the same trick that is used with the Jacobian to avoid performing the complete sum. What is the trick, then?

Comment: Is there a trick?  That would be pretty nice.  It seems to me that most methods for larger data use L-BFGS or congugate gradient methods.

Comment: Could give it a try here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/